# small font of text under table, but keeping table size itself normal

Tags: tables, fontsize

When making a table in lyx using tex coding (ERT):
I want some explanation text in a small font under the table (using \multicolumn). But when i type {\small [text]} the entire table shrinks, even if I make sure to write the \small -command just before the text that I want to be small.

```
\begin{tabular}{lccc} 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Table 1: CPA regulatory costs by risk class} \\ \hline 
Risk class & Freq. inspection & Cost inspection & Freq. system revision \\ \hline
$R_t = 1$ & Each year & 20,200 & Every 3rd year \\
$R_t = 2$ & Every 2nd year & 15,200 & Every 6th year \\
$R_t = 3$ & Every 2nd/3rd year & 11,700 & - \\
$R_t = 4$ & When needed & 4,500 & - \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Source: Lovdata - Forurensningsforskriften} \\
\end{tabular}
```

I only want the line with `\multicolumn{4}{c}{Source: Lovdata - Forurensningsforskriften}` to be small.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Could `\multicolumn{4}{c}{\tiny Source: Lovdata - Forurensningsforskriften}` do it? Alternatively, you could have the source in the `table` `caption`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccc} 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Table 1: CPA regulatory costs by risk class} \\ \hline 
Risk class & Freq. inspection & Cost inspection & Freq. system revision \\ \hline
$R_t = 1$ & Each year & 20,200 & Every 3rd year \\
$R_t = 2$ & Every 2nd year & 15,200 & Every 6th year \\
$R_t = 3$ & Every 2nd/3rd year & 11,700 & - \\
$R_t = 4$ & When needed & 4,500 & - \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\scriptsize Source: Lovdata - Forurensningsforskriften} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

Comment: @Marit Use the `caption`? If you add `\usepackage[hang,bf,small]{caption}` there's no big deal having long captions =)

Comment: Both suggestions (\sciptsize and \tiny) worked very well! Thank you :) Only, it looks a bit strange when I add more lines than the one mentioned (additional explanations to the table). The font looks small, but I would also like the line spacing to be tighter (similar to text in footnotes). Is there also a command for tightening the line spacing in a table?

Comment: @Marit I don't know. Maybe that is another question =)

Comment: True that! Anyways, using \scriptsize tha spacing seemed more natural compared to the font size, so I'll go with that :)